# smarty assign an interface

Tags: php, smarty

I have an interface that I am trying to assign to a smarty variable. In Smarty 3 support for class contants was added and I am trying to take advantage of it.

```
namespace Application;
interface ServerResponseCodes
{
    const FAILURE = 0;
    const SUCCESS = 1;
    const PENDING = 2;
    const INVALID = 3;
}
```

And then

```
$smarty->assign("codes", Application\ServerResponseCodes);
```

throws an error

> Fatal error: Undefined constant 'Application\ServerResponseCodes' in
>   /home/parvhraban/domains/src/www_root/clienttest.php on line 16

Is that possible to access interface consts from the smarty template?

Is there a limitation that I can assign only initialized objects?

Any better and more native solution that a reflection class?

```
$codes = new ReflectionClass ('Application\ServerResponseCodes');
$smarty->assign("codes", $codes->getConstants());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error doesn't have to do with Smarty, nor is a Smarty script generating it. This is a PHP syntax issue.

Normally you must make an instance of the class:

```
$smarty->assign("codes", new Application\ServerResponseCodes);
```

However in your case this won't work as interfaces cannot be instantiated on their own. To access the codes I think you'll need to use another class that implements this interface.

```
class MyClass implements ServerResponseCodes {}

$smarty->assign("codes", new MyClass);
```

However seeing your question update, using `ReflectionClass` seems like a better option. I'm certain there is an even better option but it requires more knowledge of your application. It seems odd to need these values in a Smarty template.

Comment: I want to avoid harcoding magic numbers inside the template. There is an ajax call being sent to server API that returns a magic number and I wanted to pass the interface to the template. Those magic numbers are used in the template I am afraid

Comment: I'll give you the benefit of the doubt on that. However, related to your problem, there are multiple workarounds. I'm afraid you cannot access an interface directly (in PHP) unless it is from a class that implements it, and you cannot pass references to classes around by their name unless it is a string value (or variable holding an instance of that class). I'm nearly certain that if you use a class name without `new` it must use `::` after.

Comment: Why can't you just pass in the relevant status code? Do you have business logic in your Smarty template?

Comment: There is a client sending request to the server. A response has a magic number and depending on that number the template shows different content. I do not think that moving that logic to php makes sense so I will stick to reflection class solution. Thank you for the response, an idea with object is also interesting :-)